# Printing Long Spreadsheets on One Page (Excel to PDF)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a time based chart and I am trying to print it on one pdf page. The chart spreads from column 'B' to 'UR' ~ 560 columns. I have the print setup for that area and to fit one page. It prints till column JU and disregards the rest. Not sure if there is a work around or if I am missing something. And if there is a vba script that can help with it.

Comment: I created a single chart that spanned 563 columns from B through UR and "saved" (as opposed to printed) it as a .PDF with no formatting issues. Are you printing to PDF or saving as PDF? If printing then try saving. If saving as PDF, have you tried a simple example to see whether it is some unknown issue (potentially) related to the complexity of the chart?

Comment: Did you change any setting in the 'options' while saving the pdf. I have tried both, saving and printing.

Comment: Also what was you paper size used in the page setup.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some additional variations and did experience the cut off issue. I couldn't quickly work out what created the limit, but it wasn't the number of columns; a **guess** is there is a limit to the size of the hidden "canvas" on which the chart is painted before its scaled back to print and/or save as PDF ... hence is related to the width of the chart. However you can see (roughly) from the screen shots below a chart spanning from B to UR (limited by yellow in column UR); the chart is 319cm wide. Then the saved PDF. The page setup was A4 landscape with narrow margins. Cheers.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Not sure if you mean that you found a work around or not.

Comment: So yes, while I imagine that circumstances may vary given the factors involved, but a workaround would seem to be that limiting the chart size to ~319cm allows it to be saved as a PDF per the working example that I've shown.

Comment: I have my paper size set as letter (US equivalent of A4). And I have the width and height as 1 page. When saving it as a pdf, it saves as multiple pages.

Comment: I just came up with the worst work around. Copied the chart, pasted as JPEG. Copied the JPEG to PowerPoint and saved the image as a JPEG. The converted the JPEG to a PDF. Man, that is a lot of work.